# How to create Latex table with multiple row categories (such as subcategories)?

Tags: tables

I wish to create something similar to the following table

[image]

where Ozeki and Yokozuna are categories. I, II, III, etc. are sub categories, and Azuma, Santoro, Kenzo are items in the first column. The cells are to be inputted either numerical values or strings.

I am quite familiar with how to create something like

[image]

but clueless as to how to add that first "grand" category. I don't even know what type of table I should use.

A minimal example should suffice. Outer border is not needed.

Comment: Take a look at the multicolumn command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, as @leandriis suggests in a comment, `\multicolumn` will help you there. Here's a snippet that also uses the `booktabs` package to create a nice-looking table:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
\toprule
                     & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Ozeki}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Yokozuna}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-8}
                     & I & II &            III            & I & II & III &           IV           \\
\midrule
    \textbf{Azuma}   &   &    &                           &   &    &     &                        \\
    \textbf{Santoro} &   &    &                           &   &    &     &                        \\
    \textbf{Kenzo}   &   &    &                           &   &    &     &                        \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Do please change "Yokuzuna" to "Yokozuna", though. :-)

Comment: @Mico thanks for the upvote --- and I did wonder about that, but the OP had "Yokuzuna" as well, so I stuck with that!

Comment: Well, just because the OP's text had a typo...

Comment: ありがとうございました!!!!

Comment: @Norman どういたしまして!

Comment: @Norman BTW, if this answer helped you, it'd be nice if you could accept it by clicking on the checkmark symbol.